# How to convert Singleton Class from swift 2 to swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to convert this syntax to swift 3 but as I am very new to swift cannot understand the syntax. I need to create a singleton class of Almofire manager and create its singleton instance.
Here is my old code can anyone suggest code which supports swift 3?

```
    class AlamofireManager: NSObject
{
    private static var __once: () = {
            Static.instance = AlamofireManager()
        }()
    var req:Request?

    var baseUrl:String!

    var user:String?
    var password:String?

    var manager:SessionManager!

    /*
    *Singleton method
    */
    class var sharedInstance: AlamofireManager {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken: Int = 0
            static var instance: AlamofireManager? = nil
        }
        _ = AlamofireManager.__once
        return Static.instance!
    }



    override init() {
        self.manager = Alamofire.SessionManager()
    }
}
```

Comment: use shared instance like this

Comment: This *is* a duplicate and there are >80 Q&A's for "Swift 3 singleton".

Answer (score 0):

Use Shared instance

final class SingletonClass {

```
// Can't init is singleton
private init() { }

//   Shared Instance

static let shared = SingletonClass()

//   Local Variable

var yourArray : [String] = []

}
```

initialize like :-  SingletonClass.sharedinstance.yourArray. = initialize